# Edge is putting image URL on IFRAME src adds margin by few number inside IFRAME body

Tags: iframe, microsoft-edge

In the iframe src when i put image url , the image renders in the iframe but with  default margin. how can we eliminate that margin.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about the space that we can see in image below between image and Iframe?

[image]

To eliminate that margin try to add CSS below in child page.

```css
html,body
{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  border:0px;
}

iframe
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Output:

[image]

If this is not your issue then try to provide a sample code and provide detailed information about your issue.

We will again try to provide further suggestions to the issue.

Comment: create a sample html page

Comment: create a sample html page with following markup 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81TLnz7wJvL.png"></iframe>
<style>
iframe
{
border:0px;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>

and browse that file in the edge, and see the image is coming with some margin in case of edge broswer.

Comment: I made a test with your code and it display the margin on other browsers too. solution will be the same that I suggested you in my previous reply. It can help you to remove that margin.

Comment: on chrome the margin does not comes inside Iframe. and i don't know how are u sure about your solution, as ur solution can be applicable on iframe itself not inside the body of iframe.

Comment: one more thing, i don't have the child page, user can add the image url in the iframe source directly. so this problem is related to putting image url in the iframe source. Please see the title and description of my queries, i believe you missed it

Comment: I again try to make a test with image as a source of an iframe and i am able to produce the issue. If you check code in developer tools, It like it is adding another HTML inside frame. https://i.postimg.cc/8k4bp4VL/18.png  I try to modify my code and try to access the window or content of an iframe but it looks like it is not working. Things I had tried : https://textuploader.com/dnb77 I will try to log this issue for Edge, so that developers of the Edge can come to know about this issue.

Comment: cool that i already know. browser renders only html , so when we try to render the image, the browser wraps a <img/> tag inside a default html ,body markup to show the image. that dafault added <body/>  comes up with margin